# Visual C++ - Среда разработки

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Какую доступную (с кряками) весрсию Visual C++ Вы можете порекомендовать.

В целях обучения и дальнейшего использования.

З.Ы. 2010 версию в Сети нету.

Comment: Visual C++ Express можно бесплатно скачать на сайте Microsoft

Comment: Мне не удаётся создавать приложения с компонентами на Express"е.
И рекомендовали полную версию...

Comment: ру-трекер уже не тот? xD

Comment: А версию сказать, не судьба??? Хорошую!!

Comment: @romanzi Версию MSVC++, которая не требует участия программиста в процессе разработки? Мне тоже интересно.

Comment: Я имею в виду на которой хорошо учится и ещё более менее современная.
Начинал с 6.0. но она старая-старая...
Есть Express 2008 но там оконные приложения делать нельзя...

Мне интересна хорошая версия Visual...
Как же с Вами, сишниками тяжело(

Comment: @ildar Там нет главного -- кряков. Крякать приходится самому.

Comment: вперед и с песней http://www.dreamspark.ru/

сам скачал недавно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ru-ru/products/2010-editions/express). [Скачать](http://www.microsoft.com/ru/ru/softmicrosoft/vsexpress.aspx). Там есть все, что нужно новичку и даже больше. Оконные приложения в том числе.
Думаю, в Express 2008 оконные тоже есть.

Comment: Express версию не нужно крякать. Она конечно требует регистрации, но она бесплатная. Нужно только пройти бесплатную регистрацию в службе Windows Live, там серийный номер выдается бесплатно.

Answer (score 0):

Даёшь [MS Visual Studio 11 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/ru-ru/downloads) и [C++ 11](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)